# How do I extract individual OPUS frames, one by one from a .webm file

Tags: go, webm, opus

I have a .webm file that contains only audio encoded in the OPUS codec (no video). I want to know how i can extract each individual OPUS frame from the file without decoding it into PCM and re-encoding it.

Comment: WEBM is a container (actually, it's Matroska). So you write code to parse Matroska container format and then code to parse audio codec's frames out of it. The specifications of these formats are open. This question is not related to Go.

Comment: …and surely people did already write some code to deal with both parts—see [this](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=matroska&m=package) and [this](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=opus&m=package).